# Jboss automatically calls the PL procedures of the DB Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jboss, procedure

What I pose is a problem I believe on the jboss side:

in this case I have an asynchronous method (server side) that makes a normal call to a PL procedure on an Oracle DB.

This procedure can take up to 12/15 minutes to finish.

I noticed that after exactly 5 minutes a second call to the PL procedure is automatically performed, I suspect that this call is made by Jboss.

Does anyone know if there is a property or some parameter to modify that by default is worth 5 minutes (360000) and how to take it for example 10 minutes?

Comment: What version of JBoss are you using? How did you implement the asynchronous call (via JMS, @Asynchronous, something else)? What does your service do besides calling the query? Are you using any custom interceptors? - My _guess_ based on the information you've provided so far: the transaction reaper kills the current transaction after the default 5 minute timeout (which is 300 seconds or 300000 millis btw) and some mechanism (that depends on how you implemented it) starts a retry.

Comment: jboss 4.2.3.
asynchronous call via JMS.
where can I change the timeout value of the transaction reaper kills?

Comment: Well, it's been a while since I last used a JBoss 4.2.3 but in jboss-service.xml theres an mbean called "TransactionManager" and this one has an attribute called "TransactionTimeout" with a value of 300. IIRC that one would be the default timeout (also have a look [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/TransactionTimeout)) but I'd not recommend changing that. Instead you should be able to set a timeout on the message driven bean alone via JBoss' one `@TransactionTimeout`.